# Java error passing enum and String varargs

Tags: java, enums, lotus-domino, variadic-functions

I need some understanding of what I'm running into with an issue. I have a method with the signature `addTerm(enum, String, String...)` but when use it I get an error that says *The method addTerm(Comparison, String, String...) in the type FTSearchBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Comparison, String, String, String)* - I also get the same error if I pass only a single string. Initially, I thought this was a problem with my vararg, but through testing I've found that if I change the initial argument from a Comparison to a String, my method works just fine. However, I have not had issues with passing an enum in other methods. Can anyone explain what is going on and how to fix this?

Code below in case it is useful.

**Error**

```
FTSearchBuilder sb = new FTSearchBuilder();
sb.addTerm(Comparison.EQ, "Form", "frmClaim", "frmClaimstub");
```

**Works** (with slight modification to addTerm to use String instead of enum)

```
FTSearchBuilder sb = new FTSearchBuilder();
sb.addTerm("=", "Form", "frmClaim", "frmClaimstub");
```

**Comparison**

```
public enum Comparison {
    LT("<"), LTE("<="), EQ("="), GTE(">="), GT(">");

    private final String text;

    private Comparison(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

**addTerm()** (within FTSearchBuilder class)

```
public class FTSearchBuilder {
private String query;

public FTSearchBuilder() {
    query = "";
}

public String getQuery() {
    return this.query;
}

public void addTerm(Comparison operator, String fieldName, String... values) {
    // Validate input
    String queryTerm = "";
    if (0 == values.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("No comparison values given");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(values[x])) {
            if (queryTerm.equals("")) {
                queryTerm += "([" + fieldName + "]" + operator.getText() + enquote(values[x]);
            } else {
                queryTerm += " | [" + fieldName + "]" + operator.getText() + enquote(values[x]);
            }
            queryTerm += ")";
        }
    }

    if (!query.equals("")) {
        this.query += "&";
    }
    this.query += queryTerm;
}

public void addDateTerm(Comparison operator, String fieldName, String... values) {
    // Validate input
    String queryTerm = "";
    if (0 == values.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("No comparison values given");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(values[x])) {
            if (queryTerm.equals("")) {
                queryTerm += "([" + fieldName + "]" + operator.getText() + values[x];
            } else {
                queryTerm += " | [" + fieldName + "]" + operator.getText() + values[x];
            }
            queryTerm += ")";
        }
    }

    if (!query.equals("")) {
        this.query += "&";
    }
    this.query += queryTerm;
}

private String enquote(String s) {
    return "\"" + s + "\"";
}
}
```

Comment: Is your `Comparison` called something different in the actual code?

Comment: This is all actual code copied and pasted right from my application. I trimmed an unrelated static function out of `Comparison` for getting the right comparison for a `String`.

Comment: Do you have any overloads of the method you're trying to call? Something else you could try is calling with an array e.g. `...addTerm(Comparison.EQ, "s0", new String[] { "s1", "s2" })`.

Comment: I tried `sb.addTerm(Comparison.EQ, "Form", new String[] {"frmClaim", "frmClaimstub"});` and I got the same thing: _The method addTerm(Comparison, String, String...) in the type FTSearchBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Comparison, String, String[])_. Edit: correction no overloads.

Comment: Please post your code for `FTSearchBuilder`; also, do you have any other methods named `addTerm`?

Comment: There must be something in the code you are not showing us. Given the above code the version passing the enum should work and the version passing the string should not compile. There is no implicit conversion from String to enum. Using the string version, put a breakpoint in your addTerm method add see if you get there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've edited my code above to include the full FTSearchBuilder class.

Comment: @GaryForbis I see that. Are you sure you're building this code? There should not be an assignable statement to pass String instead of your enum. Also, do you have another Comparison class? Maybe try a full package name instead of bare Comparison. Finally, is `addDateTerm` working?

Comment: Are these classes in the same project? Is the calling code in a different project and using an old / different version of the project containing FTSearchBuilder. Again, I would suggest using the String version and setting the breakpoint. See where you get.

Comment: I'm getting an error in Eclipse when I build. I will check to make sure there isn't another version of Comparison hiding in another package. When I said I changed it to a String, I changed the addTerm method to accept a String instead of Comparison. I can post that alternate code, but it is just changing Comparison to String and changing `operator.getText()` to just `operator`.

Comment: Ohhhhh..... Yeah, I think you are getting different `Comparison` classes. Check the imports.

Comment: Well that is embarrassing... that was the issue. There was both a local and plugin version that were causing the conflict. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future troubleshooters - the problem isn't in the code. I had been packaging up reusable code into plug-ins for use in other applications, and that included everything here. I still had the local copy of the package and the plug-in had been added to the buildpath so there were two identical copies of the package and classes.

When I changed the signature of the FTSearchBuilder, the compiler was able to tell which one I was using because then they had different signatures and it started working, but when I changed it back it became ambiguous again and flagged an error.

I removed the local copy and everything started working just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following test and worked fine:

```
public class Test {
    enum Comparison {
        LT("<"), LTE("<="), EQ("="), GTE(">="), GT(">");

        private final String text;

        private Comparison(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return this.text;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addTerm(Comparison.EQ, "Form", "frmClaim", "frmClaimstub");
    }

    private static void addTerm(Comparison operator, String fieldName, String... values) {
        System.out.println(operator.toString());
        System.out.println(fieldName);

        if (values != null && values.length > 0){
            for (String v : values) {
                System.out.print(v + " ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
EQ
Form
frmClaim frmClaimstub
```

Could you please send us the stacktrace?

Comment: FYI, stacktrace only applies to a run-time exception not to a compile error.

Comment: Your right, I didn't notice the problem was a compile error.